# Authentication Redirect

Tags: authentication, redirect

**Background**
I'm working with a client that is using SharePoint as their web server. They are providing me with hyperlinks that point to a SharePoint page which contains a video. Now, there are two different hyperlinks that they are providing. One type is public and anyone clicking that link will be able to see that page and video. The other type is private and the user can not see the video. What they do see however is a site templated page but "access denied" where content would typically load if they were authenticated.

**Dilemma**
What I am trying to relay to the client's IT department is that I'd like it configured where the user would be redirected to the login screen and then redirect again to the intended page after successful authentication, rather than showing an "Access Denied" page. They say that can't be done.

**Questions**
What do I tell the client's IP department they need to do to make this happen?

A friend said it could be a query string that points to the authentication page but a redirect to the page they were originally requesting.

Is this a SharePoint setting?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint handles redirecting a user to authenticate when they aren't already.  Also, Access Denied error page normally means that the user is authenticated and just doesn't have permissions to see the content they are attempting to access.  This fits with your scenario since you say the page is private which implies you have already logged in.  What you need is to compare the access settings for the private page and the access settings for the video and see where they don't line up.